# Expression Tree of a Generic Action

Tags: .net, reflection, expression-trees, system.reflection

I need to build an expression tree out of `Action<T>` (if I may formulate it this way) but the problem is that the type `T` is determined at runtime via reflection.

I need to pass this expression as an argument to a generic method that gets called using the `MethodInfo.Invoke` API. The type argument for this method and the lambda mentioned above should match.

Is this achievable? Or maybe there are some better / easier ways of doing this?

Here's what the method looks like:

```
static GenericMethod<T>(Expression<Action<T>> doSomething) {  }
```

and all I need is to call it, e.g.

```
Class.GenericMethod<string>(s => { Console.Write(s.GetType()); }
```

but I need to do this dynamically at runtime.

Comment: What should the expression tree do? Just invoke the `Action<T>`? Or whatever the `Action<T>` does inside? The latter would be very hard and would effectively require decompiling code. Maybe code that doesn't compile, but shows what you logically want to do would help.

Comment: @svick, thanks for the reply, I'll try to add some example pseudo code. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

It seems you already know how to get and invoke the generic method `GenericMethod`:

```
var genericMethod = someType.GetMethod(nameof(GenericMethod), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(null, …);
```

And you probably also already know how you could create a method that creates the expression you need based on a compile-time `T`:

```
static Expression<Action<T>> CreateWriteTypeExpression<T>() =>
    s => Console.Write(s.GetType());
```

So, how to invoke this `CreateWriteTypeExpression` based on runtime `Type`? The same as above for `GenericMethod`, using reflection.

Put together it would be:

```
static Expression<Action<T>> CreateWriteTypeExpression<T>() =>
    s => Console.Write(s.GetType());

void CallGenericMethod(MethodInfo genericMethod, Type type)
{
    var writeTypeExpressionMethod = this.GetType()
        .GetMethod(nameof(CreateWriteTypeExpression), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
        .MakeGenericMethod(type);

    var writeTypeExpression = writeTypeExpressionMethod.Invoke(null, null);

    genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(null, new[] { writeTypeExpression });
}
```